# RESTful implementation of factory method design pattern

Tags: rest, design-patterns

How would you design a RESTful API for a class that uses the factory method pattern to create objects?

Let's say you have class Passport:

```
public class Passport {
   final String firstName;
   final String lastName;
   final Date   birthDate;
   State  state;

   private Passport(State state, String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
      this.state = state;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.birthDate = birthDate;
   } 


   public static Passport createPreliminary(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
       return new Passport(PRELIMINARY, firstName, lastName, birthDate);
   }

   public static Passport createRegular(String firstName, String lastName, Date birthDate) {
       return new Passport(REGULAR, firstName, lastName, birthDate);
   }

   public void invalidate() {
      state = INVALID;
   }
}

public enum State {
    PRELIMINARY,
    REGULAR,
    EXPIRED,
    INVALID
}
```

A Passport instance can be created in two different states. After creation only the state property can be changed in a restricted way via state transition methods like invalidate().

What would be the RESTful way to create Passport resources? A POST to /passports including the state property and check on the server-side that the state is either REGULAR or PRELIMINARY and return a BAD REQUEST response if it is an illegal state? Or two different URLs for creating passport resources, one for "regular" and one for "preliminary" passports?

Comment: How would you achive your needs on the Web? You'd ask the server for a resource that teaches you how a request has to be build. The server would respond with a form that offers a client a skeletton what fields and what types are necessary and also provides a convenient submit button to actually perform the request. Whether you create a `REGULAR` or a `PRELIMINARY` passport will be determined by probably a dropdown choice. The same can be applied for any REST application as well. Either reuse HTML forms or specify your own general-purpose media-types in that particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A POST to /passports including the state property and check on the server-side that the state is either REGULAR or PRELIMINARY and return a BAD REQUEST response if it is an illegal state?

This is the option I'd go for. Having one endpoint for adding to the passports resource is the simplest and the easiest to understand.

If you used the other option, every time you added/changed an item to the "State" enum, you'd have to also change your resource structure. It just introduces unnecessary complexity and causes your API design to be less flexible.

Your API should be an abstraction of your internal business logic. Don't make it complex and layered if you don't have to.

Comment: +1 for "Your API should be an abstraction of your internal business logic. Don't make it complex and layered if you don't have to."